# Move Camera to make all objects fit exactly inside the frustum - three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, intersect, plane, frustum

EDIT : I have rephrased my question to help users with the same problem.

I have a three.js scene on which I have added some spheres.

I want to move the camera towards a specific direction until all the objects (which are randomly positioned inside the scene) are "fitting exactly" the user's screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem!

**1.** I move the camera (zooming to the desired direction) inside a loop, and in every repeat I create a new frustum using the camera's matrix

**2.** I check if any of my spheres intersects with a plane of the frustum. If it does, that means that part of one of my objects is outside the frustum so I break the loop and move the camera to its last position.

The above might also works for **any object** (not only spheres) because every object has a boundingSphere that can be calculated (it might not be very precise the result though).

It also works when **zooming out**, you 'd just have to move the camera from the object until none of the has a negative distance from all the planes (negative distance means object is "outside" the plane of the frustum).

Code (only for zooming out - r72) :

```
var finished = false;
var camLookingAt = /* calc. */ ;

while( finished === false ){

var toDirection= camera.position.clone().sub(camLookingAt.clone());
toDirection.setLength(vec.length() - 1); // reduce length for zooming out
camera.position.set(toDirection.x, toDirection.y, toDirection.z);

camera.updateMatrix(); // make sure camera's local matrix is updated
camera.updateMatrixWorld(); // make sure camera's world matrix is updated

var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
frustum.setFromMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse ) );

for (var j = frustum.planes.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {  
  var p = frustum.planes[j];  
  for (var i = myMeshSpheres.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    var sphere = new THREE.Sphere(myMeshSpheres[0].position.clone(), myMeshSpheres[0].radius); 

    if( p.distanceToSphere(sphere) < 1 ){ // if is negative means part of sphere is outside plane/frustum
      finished = true; 
    } 

  } 
}
```

Comment: That seems like a really inefficient solution. I was looking for a more direct solution using the camera's frustum planes.